# How to open files in one single window when using Textmate 2

Tags: textmate, textmate2

When I want to open many files which are not in the same path or projects, I want to them to be opened in tabs not in separated windows.

Is there any setting or configuration item to do this？

I am using Textmate 2.

Thank you for any help or advise.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply list all the files you want to open separated by a space. E.g.,

`mate .zshrc .dotfiles/aliases Projects/scala/hello/src/greeter/Hello.scala`

Opens three tabs in the same TextMate window, one each for the three files listed above. You can also use `mate .` to open all files in the current directory.